# How to limit the number of TopLevel Window Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, window, toplevel

This is my code.
When i press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> it popups a TopLevel Window. However, when i press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> again, it popups up another window on top of it and so on.

How can i improve the code so that only one window Pops up when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

class MainWindow(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master

        self.master.title("Tournament Software")

        self.menu()

    def menu(self):

        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)

        participant = Menu(menu, tearoff=False)
        participant.add_command(label="Add participant", accelerator="Ctrl+S", command=self.addparticipant_window)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Participants", menu=participant)

        self.bind_all('<Control-s>', lambda e: menu.after(100,self.addparticipant_window))

    def addparticipant_window(self):
        participantWindow = Toplevel()
        participantWindow.geometry("400x350")
        participantWindow.resizable(False, False)

        top_frame = Frame(participantWindow, bg='cyan', width=450, height=50, pady=3)
        top_frame.grid(row=0, sticky="ew")

root = Tk()
root.iconbitmap("Icon.ico")
root.geometry("500x400")
root.resizable(False, False)


app = MainWindow(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Thankyou,  I am new to this so help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

class MainWindow(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master

        self.master.title("Tournament Software")

        self.menu()
        self.popup = None

    def open_up(self):
        if self.popup is None or not self.popup.top.winfo_exists():
            self.popup = addparticipant_window()
        else:
            self.popup.top.lift(self.master)

    def menu(self):

        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)

        participant = Menu(menu, tearoff=False)
        participant.add_command(label="Add participant", accelerator="Ctrl+S", command=self.open_up)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Participants", menu=participant)

        self.bind_all('<Control-s>', lambda e: menu.after(100,self.open_up))

class addparticipant_window:

    def __init__(self):
        self.top = Toplevel()
        self.top.geometry("400x350")
        self.top.resizable(False, False)

        top_frame = Frame(self.top, bg='cyan', width=450, height=50, pady=3)
        top_frame.grid(row=0, sticky="ew")

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x400")
root.resizable(False, False)


app = MainWindow(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi JJ, whilst this may answer the question it's always better to add some context and explanation as to what you did and why you did it. This helps newcomers to the languages and ideas you have discussed understand the concept easier.